# How to change get id from url to post method

Tags: url, zend-framework, post, methods

I have a code like this

```
var arr                     =   new Array();
    var cnt                     =   0;
    var checkboxes              =   $('.sel');
    var emaillist               =   document.getElementsByName("elist[]");
    var selectedContract        =   [];
    var dispflag                =   false;
    var x                       =   0;

    $.each(checkboxes,function(i,r){
        if(r.checked){
            arr[cnt++]  =   r.value;
            if(emaillist[x].value != "true"){
                dispflag = true;
                selectedContract.push(r.value);
            }
        }
        x++;
    });
    var params = selectedContract.join(':');

    if(cnt == 0)
    {
        alert("No contracts selected.");
    }
    else
    {
        url = controllerPath + "/getcontract/contract_id/" + arr + "/custom_action/1";
        window.open (url,"Contracts","resizable=1,location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=800,height=600");
    }
```

I want to change arr that give result contract_id to POST method cause when the contract_id more than 500 result, the page shows blank due to URL too large/too long.

I still don't understand how to do it.
Anyone can help me to solve it.

Comment: I am not sure, but I do not think a POST can be accomplished by simply assigning a value to window.location or passing a url where to post to window.open. For a post, you will need to use ajax.

Comment: Why don't you try jquery?